# Do comments affect performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, comments, function-prototypes

Am I correct to say that JavaScript code isn't compiled, not even JIT? If so, does that mean that comments have an affect on performance, and I should be very careful where I put place my comments? Such as placing function comments above and outside the function definition when possible, and definitely avoid placing comments inside loops, if I wanted to maximize performance? I know that in *most* cases (at least in non-loop cases), the change in performance would be negligible, but I think that this would be something that is good to know and be aware of, especially for front-end/js developers. Also, a relevant question was asked on a js assessment I recently took.

Comment: It would depend on browser I think chrome v8 has JIT compiler

Comment: Every file is parsed only a single time, when it's loaded. So it doesn't make a difference whether the comment is inside or outside of the function, interpreter doesn't see it.

Comment: So when you tested it what were your results?

Comment: The cost of comments in un-minified source is a 1000x less than the cost of developers not knowing what the heck is going on!

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev I see, thanks. So I take it that goes for loops too :)

Comment: @ConradFrix The testing I did for loop comments didn't really show any difference in performance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Am I correct to say that JavaScript code isn't compiled, not even JIT?

No. Although JavaScript is traditionally an "interpreted" language (although it needn't necessarily be), most JavaScript engines compile it on-the-fly whenever necessary. V8 (the engine in Chrome and NodeJS) used to compile immediately and quickly, then go back and aggressively optimize any code that was used a lot (the old FullCodegen+TurboFan stack); a while back having done lots of real-world measurement, [they switched](https://v8project.blogspot.co.uk/2017/05/launching-ignition-and-turbofan.html) to initially parsing to byteocde and interpreting, and then compiling if code is reused much at all (the new Ignition+TurboFan stack), gaining a significant memory savings by not compiling run-once setup code. Even engines that are less aggressive almost certainly at least parse the text into some form of bytecode, discarding comments early.

Remember that "interpreted" vs. "compiled" is usually more of an environmental thing than a language thing; there are C interpreters, and there are JavaScript compilers. Languages tend to be closely associated with environments (like how JavaScript tends to be associated with the web browser environment, even though it's always been used more widely than that, even back in 1995), but even then (as we've seen), there can be variation.

> If so, does that mean that comments have an affect on performance...

A very, very, *very* minimal one, on the initial parsing stage. But comments are very easy to scan past, nothing to worry about.

If you're really worried about it, though, you can minify your script with tools like [`jsmin`](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html#) or the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) (even with just simple optimizations). The former will just strip comments and unnecessary whitespace, stuff like that (still pretty effective); the latter does that *and* actually understands the code and does some inlining and such. So you can comment freely, and then use those tools to ensure that whatever minuscule impact those comments may have when the script is first loaded is bypassed by using minifying tools.

Of course, the thing about JavaScript performance is that it's hard to predict reliably cross-engine, because the engines vary so much. So experiments can be fun:

- [Here's](http://jsperf.com/is-there-a-cost-to-comments) an experiment which (in theory) reparses/recreates the function every time
- [Here's one](http://jsperf.com/is-there-a-cost-to-comments-v2) that just parses/creates the function once and reuses it

Result? My take is that there's no discernable difference within the measurement error of the test.

Comment: wow, fair play for the tests! They confirmed what I already knew. If people worry about performance, they should probably drop big brothers like jQuery, Tinymce and other stuff that import tens of thousands of lines of js code. A few comments can't beat those for killing performance.

Answer (score 11):

The biggest effect that comments have is to bloat the file size and thereby slow down the download of the script. Hence why all professional sites use a minimizer for a productive version to cut the js down to as small as it gets.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into minimizers.

Answer (score 4):

It may have some effect. Very minimalistic effect, though (even IE6 handles comments correctly ! *to be confirmed...*).

However, most people use a minifier that strips off comments. So it's okay.

Also:

> V8 increases performance by compiling JavaScript to native machine code before executing it.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide the reference to your quote?

Comment: Yup, added it to my answer :) Wikipedia.

Comment: Beware that you may not be allowed to remove comments from libraries you're using as they often also contain licensing information.

Answer (score 0):

It [can prevent functions from being inlined](https://floitsch.blogspot.com/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-inlining.html), which affects performance, though this shouldn't really happen.

Answer (score 0):

In some perhaps isolated circumstances, comments definitely somehow bog down the code execution. I am writing a lengthy userscript, using in the latest Firefox on Mac using TamperMonkey, and several days' increasingly frustrated troubleshooting came to an end when I stripped the lengthy comments from the script and suddenly the script execution stopped hanging completely on Facebook. Multiple back-and-forth comparisons running the same exact script on a fresh user account, the only difference being the comments, proved this to be the case.