# Is there additional overhead by using script tags for multiline comments

Tags: javascript, html

Was wondering if there are any performance issues in regards to using js over html comments (mainly like the /* vs the

```
/*
omg so many comments
must have multi line
hate the whole -->
dash arrow thing
*/
```

vs

using HTML

```
<!-- oh i am a comment
look at me
i go on for days
-->
```

Comment: to be fair I'm looking to type 3 less characters for comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[No performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232989/do-comments-affect-performance)**, however, the page is slightly slower. You have extra some bytes. But exist the `Javascript` [minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier) when the project is launched on production.

Comment: is the minification only for external calls or will it help with inline javascript?

Comment: Mostly the comments are to document a file and later are not necessary if the project is in production. The minification is only to reduce the file size "JS" as blanks and comments. This does not affect the functionality or performance. If you finish the project you can delete them, this is just a page load issue, although not much difference

Comment: As I understand it, the script is parsed by the JS engine before it is actually executed. During the parsing the slowdown is insignificant. The comments don't exist during the actual execution, so there is no performance hit... but I may be wrong (I'm inferring from the way Ruby is executed).

Comment: @wZVanG production requires comments; I.E. your whole dev team quits. and your code isn't commented and god forbid your using perl as a backend......

Comment: As @morissette correctly points out, minification will not minify JS on the HTML page. So there's just a miniscule different of two characters per comment. However, the JS comments require a `script` tag to go inside; it that's not already there, it's an extra 15 bytes. At the end of the day, though, no-one cares and it doesn't matter. Can we all spend more time making sure our code is functional, readable, and maintainable, and less time worrying about a few bytes and a few microseconds?